# Программирование под мобильные платформы

Tags: android, ios

Доброго времени суток! Сейчас довольно много фреймворков, позволяющих писать под ios/android на html5+js. Кто-нибудь использует их? можете порекомендовать какой-нибудь? Есть ли фреймворки с возможностью работы с бд/сокетами и т.п.? И вообще, с чего лучше начинать писать мобильные приложения - с такого фреймворка или objective-c/java?

Comment: android sdk + xcode?

Comment: скорее не + а  или ))

Comment: вместе они точно работать будут плохо:)

да, xcode+maxos для айось и eclipse/idea/androidstudio + linux для андроида.

Comment: может посоветуете литературу для изучения? книги,блоги и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[уроки](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom)

[тоже уроки не все бесплатные уровень пониже](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/) 
[хороший блог ios/android](http://idev.by/category/android/) 
[подборка ресурсов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/175825/)

для начала должно хватить (android)

Answer (score 7):

> Сейчас довольно много фреймворков, позволяющих писать под ios/android на html5+js.

что только человек не придумывает, что бы только не делать как нужно.

> можете порекомендовать какой-нибудь?

если просто побаловаться - так любой. Если для серьезной работы - забудьте о них.

> И вообще, с чего лучше начинать писать мобильные приложения

с изучения платформы и родных инструментов.